# dojoConfig vs djConfig

Tags: dojo

I have test to use `var dojoConfig = { async : true, parseOnLoad : true}` on dojo 1.7.1 it's ok. And I try to use `var djConfig = { async : true, parseOnLoad : true }` it's work too.

What is the difference and which I should choose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dojoConfig` is the new standard object for configurations. `djConfig` was in use until version 1.6 and they are keeping it active at least until version 2.0. I would advise you to use `dojoConfig` in all of your new projects.

> The old object name of djConfig is deprecated, but any existing code using it will continue to work up until 2.0. At the time of writing, most documentation still uses djConfig; the two "spellings" are directly equivalent, but we'll adopt and encourage use of the new dojoConfig name from here on.

Source: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dojo_config/

Comment: Thank you. If no any new answer, I will accept your answer in a few day.

Comment: Similarly, if declaring dojo config as a script tag attribute, use the new HTML5 version of `data-dojo-config` instead of the old legacy attribute.